# How do I construct a tensorflow model in keras (R) for multi-label classification?

Tags: r, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, model

I want to predict several labels with the help of a Tensorflow model using keras in R.

My training data targets: `num [1:535, 1:5]`

My training data labels (one hot encoded): `num [1:535, 1:5, 1:2]`

If I use the following model, which works for one label, for several labels (in this case 5), I get the error message

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
>   ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_43 to have 2
>   dimensions, but got array with shape (535, 5, 2)

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 50, input_shape = c(measurements)) %>% 
  layer_dropout(0.9) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')
model %>% compile(
  loss = 'binary_crossentropy',
  optimizer = "Nadam",
  metrics = 'accuracy')
history <- model %>% fit(
  data.training, data.trainLabels, 
  epochs = 10000, batch_size = 128, 
  view_metrics = FALSE, validation_split = 0.2)
```

I have tried playing with the second dense layer units (I tried 5 for the labels, 10 for labelsx2, the shape of the tensor, etc), but to no avail.

How do I need to modify my model so it can predict all 5 labels?

Comment: the last dense layer is supposed to have `units=classes+1` size

Comment: @SwapneshKhare thanks for the quick comment, but neither units=6 (I have 5 classes) nor units = 11 helps. I get the same error message.

Comment: So as per the error your training data is a 3D matrix, which is different from what you pass as target variable, both need to be of same shape of (535,5)

Comment: @SwapneshKhare my training data is the 535 samples and for each of them I have 964240 measurements, so it is a matrix of 535 x 964240, each sample has the 5 labels (0,1), which are then hot encoded. This works when I predict one label (with activation softmax instead of sigmoid).

Comment: what is the shape of `measurements`?

Comment: @SwapneshKhare in this case they are either 0 or 1 (measurement present or not in the sample), but I also have run models with a value between 0 and 1 (how present are they), which also works. Basically, measurement is just the number of columns of the training data matrix, in this case 964240, but this varies between questions I have.

Comment: I'd suggest checking out a online guide for [multi-class classification](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/). A few pointers that are quite obvious. Your loss function is currently a `binary_crossentropy`. If you are trying to predict multiple labels, it is no longer a binary output, as such this loss function will not work. This might be the entire problem but i have limited experience outside the low level tensorflow API.

Comment: @Oliver unfortunately, this is a multi-label classification (one sample can belong to multiple labels) instead of multi-class, in which case you would be correct and binary would be the wrong loss function. For my multi-label, binary should be correct as keras uses multiple binary predictions independent of each other for the prediction.